# Google Calendar API, Push notifications : Determine the source

Tags: push-notification, google-calendar-api

I would like to make a bidirectional sync between my google calendar and my website.

I've set up push notifications, everything is working well.

But there is one strange issue:

I can't determine the source of the notification.

When I delete an event in calendar, website will get a notification from google, it can check with synctoken what changed, then i can delete corresponding availability slot on my website too.

But, if i delete an availability slot on my website, PHP will delete the corresponding event in google calendar (with API), then google calendar will send a push notification to my website, and the website will delete the newly added event from the database.

The point is: 
The interaction what is fired the push notification where comes from, what is its source.

I hoped i will get different information in push notification, but those are very same.

Comment: My current solution is: I added an extended property to event with disableNotify boolean. Then i can check the changed event needs to pull the trigger or not. I'm still waiting for a better answer, if there is a better answer :)

Comment: Peter , did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @malena : Took a look at my comment below. I bit painful this part, I hope they will improve.

Comment: @Peter How did you handle this with extended property?

Comment: Without any good luck, I wasn't able to provide a perfect solution, Google Calendar just made this wrong way, there isn't a real solution for this issue.